# symfony2 assert\regex repeated characters

Tags: regex, symfony

Within Symfony2 I am trying to do annotated validation on the property $plainPassword

My assertion is:

```
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern="/(.)\\1{2}/",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="user.password.occurance",
 *    groups={"Registration","ChangePassword","ResetPassword"}
 * )
```

It's not working for some reason does anyone have an idea, basically ***aaa*** will fail and ***abc*** will pass is the expected behaviour

Not 100% sure but I am wondering if it's a bug as documented at - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5382

My composer.json is as followed:

```
    "symfony/symfony":                      "2.5",
    "doctrine/orm":                         "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
```

Comment: So you want to avoid the same character to be repeated?

Comment: basically aaa will fail and abc will pass is the expected behaviour. hover I figured it out.

Comment: With your regex, `aac` will pass. Is that your intention?

Comment: yes and aaa will fail due to > 2 of the same chars, the bellow answer did the trick but I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue

```
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern="/(.)\1{2}/",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="user.password.occurance",
 *    groups={"LendInvestRegistration","ChangePassword","ResetPassword"}
 * )
```

So I set **match=false** and removed the extra **\** before the **1**

I will set to answered once the 2 days are up.